# Comparing Datasets Comprised of Random Values and Sorting Common Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need to have two datasets of 10,000 randomly generated values between 1 and 10,000 and find only the values that are common between the datasets. I then need to sort them from least to greatest. I cannot use array_intersect() or array_unique().

It appears I was able to accomplish this using a while loop to generate the random integers for both MySQL tables and compare and sort them using a MySQL Query. I'm not completely sure if my results are accurate though and I am looking for a more efficient way to complete this task. Can someone please tell me if I am successfully completing my task and what would be alternative ways to solve this. I need to know if my Select Statement is producing the correct results and how I could improve it.

```
 <?php
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
$DB_NAME = 'e3';
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'e3';
$DB_PASS = 'exercise3password';
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
       $x = 0;
        while($x <= 10000){
        $randa = rand(1,10000);
        $randb = rand(1,10000);
$query = "INSERT into a (num) VALUES ($randa)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$query = "INSERT into b (num) VALUES ($randb)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$x++;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b on a.num=b.num WHERE a.num=b.num ORDER BY a.num";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
// GOING THROUGH THE DATA
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo stripslashes($row['num']); 
echo "<br>";
}
}
else {
echo 'NO RESULTS';  
}
// CLOSE CONNECTION
mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I updated using MySQLi. Could you look at my update code and let me know if it would work and be more efficient?

Comment: looks like a homework

Comment: It's an assignment (not homework), but I did actually code it. I am simply asking for confirmation of whether or not it is accurate and how I could make it more efficient.

Comment: The MySQLi code seems to be producing the correct results, but I just want someone to evaluate my efficiency and whether or not my SELECT Statement is correct. I don't want anyone to do the assignment for me.

Comment: Executing "SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.num = b.num WHERE a.num = b.num ORDER BY a.num" I get 10025 rows. The total number of rows is 20,000 (10,000 values per table) would this confirm that my results are accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause merely reaffirms a condition previously specified in your ON clause. As such it's redundant. Also, to improve efficiency, remove '*' and instead name each of the columns you actually want returned. Apart from that, your query is fine.